# Is it safe to keep IMAP ports for public?

Tags: security, email, email-server

I have an email server which utilizes ports: 25, 143, 465, 587, 993. As far as I understand I have to keep ports 25, 465, 587 open to public for ability to receive emails. My whole network is hidden behind VPN access (most critical services are only accessible if you're connected to VPN at this server), so can I close ports 143, 993 (and maybe one of 465 or 587?) from public not worrying about not receiving emails? One problem for sure is that I will get SSL errors due to certificate being issued for my domain, not local 10.0.0.0/8 ip. General question is: what ports from listed in the first sentence I can close without disturbing incoming and outgoing messages? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's safe to keep IMAP port open (as long as you're exposing SSL port), I'd close non-SSL ports such as: 110,143, rest you can leave open assuming you're using `STARTTLS` for your SMTP.

Comment: Sometimes client softwares of the users will want to use the 110/143. Old client software might try to login without going STARTTLS first, exposing cleartext passwords. So deny any authentication which did not happen on a non-encrypted channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the VPN to send and receive emails through this host, and only require the wider internet to send emails to your system, the only port you need open is port 25 - SMTP.  The other ports are all used by people with accounts on your system.

- Port 25 is used for sending email between systems.
- Port 465 and 587 are used for users of your system sending emails out.  You probably
  only need 1 of these to - 587 is the more commonly used port.
- Port 143 is unencrypted IMAP, and I would close it altogether.
- Port 993 is encrypted IMAP, and you need this open if you want people to be able
  to receive email without using the VPN.

SSL certs do not care about IP addresses, so the way to fix the issue with internal stuff not working with the cert because its on 10.x space, is to always use the domain name, and make sure that the domain name resolves to 10.x when queried from your LAN.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! But to be honest I want to leave here a note that I personally prefer 465 port as it is TLS, not STARTTLS, thus just a little bit more secure (e.g. against MITM).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's protected to keep IMAP port open (for however long you're exposing SSL port), I'd close non-SSL ports, for example, 110,143, rest you can leave open accepting at least for a moment that you're involving STARTTLS for your SMTP. Now and again client programming of the clients will need to utilize the 110/143.